# How to format seaborn plots

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

The following code produces 2 side-by-side plots. However, I would like to push the right plot to the right so that its label shows detached from the left plot. How can I do it? I could not find any option in `subplots`, nor in `countplot`

here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data = {
    'apples': [3, 2, 0, np.nan, 2],
    'oranges': [0, 7, 7, 2, 7],
    'figs':[1, np.nan, 10, np.nan, 10]
}
purchases = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2)

sns.countplot(purchases['apples'], ax=ax[0])
sns.countplot(purchases['oranges'], ax=ax[1])
show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `tight_layout`:

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2)

sns.countplot(purchases['apples'], ax=ax[0])
sns.countplot(purchases['oranges'], ax=ax[1])
plt.tight_layout()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your data play nicely with seaborn, consider changing your dataframe to the "long" format and plotting all categories and their corresponding count with [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot):

```
data = purchases.stack().droplevel(0).reset_index()
data.columns = ['fruit', 'number']
print(data.head(5))

# output:
#      fruit  number
# 0   apples     3.0
# 1  oranges     0.0
# 2     figs     1.0
# 3   apples     2.0
# 4  oranges     7.0

sns.catplot(data=data, x='number', kind='count', col='fruit') 
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]